# Read multiple files and combine unique rows in R

Tags: r, unique, sapply

I would like read a group of text files of unequal rows in directory and sort,combine uniq them as a matrix with filenames as column headers

for example:

file1.txt

```
  ID    COUNT
  id1     3
  id5     4
```

sample2.txt

```
  ID    COUNT
  id1    5
  id3    6
```

desired output:

```
  ID  file1  sample2  ....  
  id1  3      5
  id5  4      NA  
  id3  NA     6
```

I achieved some part on how to read files and create a list but struck with finding unique

```
   files <- list.files(path=".", pattern="\\.txt")
    samples <- list()
    for (f in files) {
            file <- read.table(f,header=F, sep="\t")
            ...
```

how can i use sapply on list of files to find unique rows in all the files?

Comment: @eipi10 - your (deleted) answer was practically there - just `reshape` to wide after the `do.call(rbind,...`

Comment: Doh! Should have read the question more carefully. See update. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)

# Read all the files into a list of data frames
df.list = lapply(files, function(file) {
  dat = read.table(file, sep="\t")
  dat$file = file
  return(dat)
}

# Combine into a single data frame
df = do.call(rbind, df.list)

# Reshape from long to wide
df = dcast(df, ID ~ file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you seek for performance:

```
library(data.table)
process = function(files){
    files = setNames(files, substr(files, 1L, nchar(files) - 4L))
    dt = rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), idcol = "file")
    dcast(dt, ID ~ file, value.var = "COUNT")
}
files = list.files(path=".", pattern="\\.txt")
process(files)
#    ID file1 sample2
#1: id1     3       5
#2: id3    NA       6
#3: id5     4      NA
```

Comment: @user2243831 my answer will work for your new file names too, but I won't write base R solution, sorry, I prefer code which not just works but also scales. You can get base R solution if you will take eipi10 answer and replace `reshape::dcast` call with some base R solution.